# What is the update for find() in Swift 3?

Tags: arrays, swift, find

I used `find()` to reference two arrays of Floats in Swift 1, but cannot find the equivalent for Swift 3.  I've tried `indexOf` and `array.first` with no luck. I've been unable to find any other alternatives. Can someone provide some guidance here?  I'm not a professional programmer and I wrote this app to help design eye prosthetics.  It worked perfectly until I updated Xcode and have had to fix about 50 issues... Never again. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 @IBAction func unitsPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let unitsAlertView = UIAlertController(title: "Units Selector", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    let mmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "millimeters", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default){
        (ACTION) in

            self.dioptorsOn = false

            self.diagnosticLensPicker.reloadAllComponents()

            if var baseCurveIndex = find(self.baseCurveArrayMM, self.chosenBaseCurveSphereMM) {  // issue is here - use of unresolved identifier "find"

            self.diagnosticLensPicker.selectRow(baseCurveIndex, inComponent: 0, animated: true)

        }

        self.unitsLabel.text = "units: mm"

    }
```

Comment: As I referenced in my question, I had attempted to use the information presented in the post you referenced, to no avail.

Comment: I agree that this isn't an exact duplicate. The question should be re-opened.